# Get Error: No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties

Tags: spring-boot

I have a project with spring-web. But it isn't a spring-boot project.  When I run the project, I get an error: `No qualifying bean of type org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties`. How can I solve it?

Comment: did you solve it? the accepted answer does not solve the problem because we don't want to create an instance, we want Spring give that instance via autowire, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try add a dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot` if you do not have one already and then declare a `BuildProperties` bean:

```
@Bean
BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    return new BuildProperties();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

See if adding the below to your pom.xml (assuming it's a maven project) helps.

```
<build>
        <finalName>{NAME_YOUR_PROJECT}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is better explained here: https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/

Note that in my IDE (Intellij), the change to pom was only detected after I ran a "maven clean verify" from the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

This could be happening for any number of reasons. For me, it happened after I upgraded IntelliJ. The build-info goal was already in the POM. My solution (which is also a comment on the most highly-voted answer) was to simply do a maven clean. Then everything was happy again.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have build-info goal in your pom.xml and you are trying to run your project from Intellij or another IDE, you might face this issue.

The solution is to simply run `mvn package` which will generate the build-info.properties needed for the startup.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was an advice from my colleague to place the build-info properties where eclipse expects it:

```
mkdir -p ./bin/main/META-INF/

cp ./build/resources/main/META-INF/build-info.properties ./bin/main/META-INF/build-info.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to add to your MAIN class (eg. MainApplication)

```
@Bean
BuildProperties buildProperties() {
    return new BuildProperties(new Properties());
}
```

Comment: In this case, BuildProperties is empty. In my case, it was an IDE Problem. I reimported the project and the error was gone  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-build-properties